# Websocket, Error 404 in voltrb

Tags: voltrb

I tried deploying a volt application using Docker via cloud66.
The image is deployed, the page is accessible but i can not login because i get the error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mps_sports_c66.totole.xyz/socket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Is there something special to do while deploying with a docker image?

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Websockets upgrade a http connection, so if you can get stuff back from the http request, then the issue is that cloud66 has a non-websocket compatible http proxy between you and your server.

http://community.cloud66.com/articles/cloud-66-websocket-support

I added a config option (on master) to specify the websocket url, see the docs here: https://github.com/voltrb/docs/blob/master/en/deployment/README.md#custom-socket-url  To run off of master, change your gemfile to use:

`gem 'volt', github: 'voltrb/volt'`

then run `bundle`

If you get things working on cloud66, would you mind adding docs for setting it up to the docs repo?  https://github.com/voltrb/docs

Thanks!